# How to match values between two objects and create new with specific values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, recursion, javascript-objects

I've array of objects `oDataSet` and `aProperties` object and I want to match the **identical** values that are found in `aPropertis` and and In `oDataSet` and create the **aSelectedDataSet** which in **beginning** is an empty object

How it's recommend to do it in JS/Jquery

Note: there shouldnt be any **hardcoded** **property** in the loops/solution to do the match 
the aProperties is contain this value but it can be change (and of course there should be match in the oData object...)

For clarification Following is example how the objects is built

http://jsfiddle.net/4rh6tt25/5/

**This is the input**

```
 //This is given array of object which can be many ,here I put just two instance in the array for demonstration purpose
var oDataSet = [{
    __metadata: {
        aaa: 111,
        bbb: 222
    },
    to_ExcludedTerms: {results: []},
    to_ListTypeGroupAssignment: {
        results: [
            {
                AuthorisationGroup: 'AuthorisationGroup 1',
                ListTypeGroup: 'ListTypeGroup1',
                ListTypeGroupDescription: 'ListTypeGroupDescription 1',
                ParentKey: '8ae25d47-c3cc-4ee3-a040-ea00505692111',
                __metadata: {}
            },
            {
                AuthorisationGroup: 'AuthorisationGroup 2',
                ListTypeGroup: 'ListTypeGroup2',
                ListTypeGroupDescription: 'ListTypeGroupDescription 2',
                ParentKey: '34bcdc74-ab42-4538-8657-0a2b0473fcb7',
                __metadata: {}
            },
            {
                AuthorisationGroup: 'AuthorisationGroup 3',
                ListTypeGroup: 'ListTypeGroup3',
                ListTypeGroupDescription: 'ListTypeGroupDescription 3',
                ParentKey: '34bcdc74-ab42-4538-8657-0a2b0473fcb5',
                __metadata: {}
            }
        ]
    }
}, {
    //This is the second instance of the object with same keys but different values
    __metadata: {
        aaa: 333,
        bbb: 444
    },
    to_ExcludedTerms: {results: []},
    to_ListTypeGroupAssignment: {
        results: [
            {
                AuthorisationGroup: 'AuthorisationGroup 6',
                ListTypeGroup: 'ListTypeGroup6',
                ListTypeGroupDescription: 'ListTypeGroupDescription 6',
                ParentKey: '8ae25d47-c3cc-4ee3-a040-ea00505692116',
                __metadata: {}
            },
            {
                AuthorisationGroup: 'AuthorisationGroup 7',
                ListTypeGroup: 'ListTypeGroup7',
                ListTypeGroupDescription: 'ListTypeGroupDescription 7',
                ParentKey: '34bcdc74-ab42-4538-8657-0a2b0473fcb7',
                __metadata: {}
            },
            {
                AuthorisationGroup: 'AuthorisationGroup 8',
                ListTypeGroup: 'ListTypeGroup8',
                ListTypeGroupDescription: 'ListTypeGroupDescription 8',
                ParentKey: '34bcdc74-ab42-4538-8657-0a2b0473fcb8',
                __metadata: {}
            }
        ]
    }
}
];

//This is the values which I should search find in oDataSet
//The to_ListTypeGroupAssignment or other property which under the same structure
//should be with the following path but under the results which is the only
//hardcoded property
var aProperties = [
    "to_ListTypeGroupAssignment/ListTypeGroup",
    "to_ListTypeGroupAssignment/ListTypeGroupDescription"
]
```

**This is the output**

This is example of the output which should be build from the **merge of both objects** in the input above

```
var aSelectedDataSet = [
    {
        __metadata: {
            aaa: 111,
            bbb: 222
        },
        to_ListTypeGroupAssignment: {
            results: [
                {
                    ListTypeGroup: 'ListTypeGroup1',
                    ListTypeGroupDescription: 'ListTypeGroupDescription 1'
                },
                {
                    ListTypeGroup: 'ListTypeGroup2',
                    ListTypeGroupDescription: 'ListTypeGroupDescription 2',

                },
                {
                    ListTypeGroup: 'ListTypeGroup3',
                    ListTypeGroupDescription: 'ListTypeGroupDescription 3',
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        __metadata: {
            aaa: 333,
            bbb: 444
        },
        to_ListTypeGroupAssignment: {
            results: [
                {
                    ListTypeGroup: 'ListTypeGroup1',
                    ListTypeGroupDescription: 'ListTypeGroupDescription 1'
                },
                {
                    ListTypeGroup: 'ListTypeGroup2',
                    ListTypeGroupDescription: 'ListTypeGroupDescription 2',

                },
                {
                    ListTypeGroup: 'ListTypeGroup3',
                    ListTypeGroupDescription: 'ListTypeGroupDescription 3',
                }
            ]
        }
    }

]
```

just to clarify from the comments below :) 
The only thing that can be **hard-coded** is the `results`.
**Not** any property name like ListTypeGroup& ListTypeGroupDescription
This should be **generic** and read from aProperties

The structure of you look at the oData should be like following

```
property(like -> to_ListTypeGroupAssignmen)
        results(hardcoded & mandatory in every exist object)
             properties(like ListTypeGroup& ListTypeGroupDescription with there values)
```

If I need to make it more clear please let me know How,which additional info I should add...This is after I update the question as much as possible...

Comment: Can you please replace the image with code? It is much easier for people to try and reconstruct your issue copying and pasting code, rather than reading it from an image. See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Map it: `oPushedObject = oData.map(function(o) {
  return {
    ListTypeGroup: o.ListTypeGroup,
    ListTypeGroupDescription: o.ListTypeGroupDescription
  };
});` ???

Comment: @A.Wolff - Im tring it now and let yo know in 2 min :)

Comment: @A.Wolff - Its a bit more complicated :( I dont want to use the key hardcoded as you put (listTypeGroup & listTypeGroupDescription) ....

Comment: So what is your expected behaviour??? If not hardcoded, how do you target specific object keys?

Comment: @A.Wolff - if there is match between those values in the both object (here is ---> listTypeGroup & listTypeGroupDescription) but it can be any values that exist in both object and then add it to oPushedObject...

Comment: Related (perhaps): http://stackoverflow.com/q/7364150/215552

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - can you please provide example with my context

Comment: Part of learning to program is to program stuff yourself. How about you try to apply that related question to your own code, then ask a specific question regarding where you're having an issue?

Comment: Then do nested loops to check for relevant properties. But your initial question was really unclear and you don't show many effort, do you???  That's said, see if that fits your needs: https://jsfiddle.net/m6zg8gcw/

Comment: @A.Wolff - I update the fiddle with my exact needed please have a look and see if you can help ,Thanks https://jsfiddle.net/m6zg8gcw/12/

Comment: @A.Wolff - I need the undifend values in the oPushedObject to be filled ....but not hard coded :)

Comment: @A.Wolff - sorry this is the right https://jsfiddle.net/m6zg8gcw/13/

Comment: http://underscorejs.org/ Is a good library for this kind of task. You can use _.findWhere or _.isMatch to find properties of objects to compare them

Comment: @ThomasIllingworth - Thanks but I cannot use undersocre and lodash in our project :(

Comment: @A.Wolff - is it a problem ?what do you think ? thank you!

Comment: What's a hardcoded property?

Comment: Please re-read the official [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) article, and adjust your post accordingly. You're not describing your problem all that well, your code is not minimal, and you haven't shown what you've tried so far, why you think that should work, what you see it do instead, and why you can't figure out why that is wrong.

Comment: The only problem I see is that your search values don't follow the object path exactly as you have it in the object you need to search.  Wouldn't `"to_ListTypeGroupAssignment/results/ListTypeGroup"` make a little more sense, otherwise you have to hardcode the check for a property name "results"

Comment: @StefanoNardo - hardcoded like listTypeGroup etc

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond - only results can be hardcoded :) forgat to mention this

Comment: @A.Wolff - please see my update question with fiddle and bounty ,Thanks :)

Comment: That much comments basically means that the question is poorly asked. We don't know how the output is supposed to look like and it's not clear how you want the "mapping" to behave. A bounty for an unspecific question can also be seen as a waste of time for posters since there is no "good answers" for that. Please improve your question by asking something specific, e.g. something that didn't work as expected in what you tried. If I understand correctly, you shown us the code for what you don't want to do. You should show us what you actually want to do. A bounty cannot improve a question.

Comment: @Frederik.L - Thanks but I think you missed the point here...most of the comments  was to the original question which I update today dramtically and create JsFiddle , The output should be aSelectedDataSet I put and example how it should be created(with the values),in addition at the bottom of the fiddle you can see what I try ,without success :(

Comment: I'm sorry but I must insist: you keep poorly asking what's your need, so even with good will nobody can really understand it. You seem to be always hurried, and it's not the good way to reach your goal. So please take the time to refactor your question _in a clear way_! Otherwise the time you're looking to save will be actually lost for you (because you'll not get any answer)... and for us!

Comment: @cFreed OP also seems to have fake accounts or friends who constantly up-votes the question. It has many downvotes, yet it has a very positive score for such an unclear question.

Comment: As suggested in meta, bounty protected questions that would need to be closed can be flagged. Otherwise it could be downvoted, which isn't a solution here since the OP always finds a way to get his score back up to positive.

Comment: @Frederik.L - question with bounty cannot be deleted,why this question bother you ,if I need to improve please tell how ? if you are here to really  help people?

Comment: @cFreed - can you tell me how it can be improved and i'll do that asap

Comment: @shopiaT It would be easier to understand your question if it was shorter and if it had only a specific part of the whole thing. The problem is, and of course I'm here to help people, is that people cannot figure out easily what could be the optimal answer to that question so they won't take the time to write one. Still trying to help, a good question should be a question for which the community would like to have an answer too. If this is a big picture with complex constraints, community won't benefit from the answer anyway and it's less tempting to put time into it. Keep it simple and clear.

Comment: @shopiaT Bounty questions CAN be deleted, if it comes to the attention of a mod. They aren't mean at all, in fact they just fight really hard against natural tendencies we have to ask questions for ourselves. That's one thing that puts SO to another level IMO.

Comment: @Frederik.L - please guide me how since at first the question was too short (two days ago) and I try to elaborate yesterday which is not so good also as you said ,Im stuck with it here can you help ? and pls remove your comment which is really screw my day :(

Comment: @Frederik.L - please be specific of what I can improve and I'll do it ASAP!Thanks

Comment: Why is your `aSelectedDataSet` returning 3 duplicate result sets?

Comment: @NickDeBeer - Hi Nick I've update the question is it more clear now ?

Comment: Yes thanks that makes sense, one more thing, should this only be for property to_ListTypeGroupAssignment or can you potentially have "__metadata/aaa" or "to_ExcludedTerms/some value" included in the result? In other words can the above values ever exist in `aProperties`?

Comment: @NickDeBeer - not necessarily

Comment: Really wish we could vote to close questions with an open bounty. This question is unclear.

Comment: From the example you have given its clear you want to merge two set of data with one of them missing some properties. Please confirm if this is the case ?

Comment: @Thanigainathan- the aSelectedDataSet is empty and should be created after the "merge" between the objects in the input

Comment: I don't get it. Which objects from the input are "merged"? All I can see is a bit of trivial filtering of properties.

Comment: Why do you want `__metadata` to be in the result, when it is not specified in `aProperties`?

Comment: @Bergi - The object values inside aProperties should be merged into the new object aSelectedDataSet,is it more clear now?

Comment: @trincot - yes I know the 'results' and '__metadata' should be there for any type of properties (the sturcture of them is hard-coded but only for them...)\

Comment: Why do you ***not*** include the `__metadata` of the inner objects then!? Is that another unspecified exception to an unspecified exception? You really need to get your question right.

Comment: So you are using aProperties as the schema and filter out other properties in the result except metadata and results. Am I right ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this recursive, pure JavaScript function:

The snippet below applies this function to the example data you provided and returns the required result:

```js
function extract(data, select, curpath) {
    var result = {};
    // Part of the path that has been traversed to get to data:
    curpath = curpath || '';        
    if (typeof data !== 'object') { // data is a primitive (we assume)
        return data;
    } 
    if (typeof data.slice === 'function') { // data is an Array
        return data.map(function (el, idx) {
            return extract(el, select, curpath); // same path!
        });
    }
    // data is an Object:
    // The specific case of the "__metadata" property
    if (data.__metadata !== undefined && curpath.length === 0) {
        result.__metadata = data.__metadata;
    }
    // Core of this algorithm: take the relevant paths only...
    var subselect = select.filter(function(path) {
        return (path+'/').indexOf(curpath) == 0;
    });
    subselect.forEach(function (path, _, subselect) {
        // then get the next property in such path...
        var prop = path.substr(curpath.length).split('/')[0];
        // and check if we have that property on the current object:
        if (data[prop] !== undefined) {
            // If so, recurse while adding this to the current path:
            result[prop] = extract(data[prop], subselect, curpath+prop+'/');
        }
    });
    // The specific case of the "results" property
    if (data.results !== undefined) {  // recurse with same path!
        result.results = extract(data.results, select, curpath);
    }
    return result;
} 


// Test data
var oDataSet = [{
    __metadata: {
        aaa: 111,
        bbb: 222
    },
    to_ExcludedTerms: {results: []},
    to_ListTypeGroupAssignment: {
        results: [
            {
                AuthorisationGroup: 'AuthorisationGroup 1',
                ListTypeGroup: 'ListTypeGroup1',
                ListTypeGroupDescription: 'ListTypeGroupDescription 1',
                ParentKey: '8ae25d47-c3cc-4ee3-a040-ea00505692111',
                __metadata: {}
            },
            {
                AuthorisationGroup: 'AuthorisationGroup 2',
                ListTypeGroup: 'ListTypeGroup2',
                ListTypeGroupDescription: 'ListTypeGroupDescription 2',
                ParentKey: '34bcdc74-ab42-4538-8657-0a2b0473fcb7',
                __metadata: {}
            },
            {
                AuthorisationGroup: 'AuthorisationGroup 3',
                ListTypeGroup: 'ListTypeGroup3',
                ListTypeGroupDescription: 'ListTypeGroupDescription 3',
                ParentKey: '34bcdc74-ab42-4538-8657-0a2b0473fcb5',
                __metadata: {}
            }
        ]
    }
}, {
    __metadata: {
        aaa: 333,
        bbb: 444
    },
    to_ExcludedTerms: {results: []},
    to_ListTypeGroupAssignment: {
        results: [
            {
                AuthorisationGroup: 'AuthorisationGroup 6',
                ListTypeGroup: 'ListTypeGroup6',
                ListTypeGroupDescription: 'ListTypeGroupDescription 6',
                ParentKey: '8ae25d47-c3cc-4ee3-a040-ea00505692116',
                __metadata: {}
            },
            {
                AuthorisationGroup: 'AuthorisationGroup 7',
                ListTypeGroup: 'ListTypeGroup7',
                ListTypeGroupDescription: 'ListTypeGroupDescription 7',
                ParentKey: '34bcdc74-ab42-4538-8657-0a2b0473fcb7',
                __metadata: {}
            },
            {
                AuthorisationGroup: 'AuthorisationGroup 8',
                ListTypeGroup: 'ListTypeGroup8',
                ListTypeGroupDescription: 'ListTypeGroupDescription 8',
                ParentKey: '34bcdc74-ab42-4538-8657-0a2b0473fcb8',
                __metadata: {}
            }
        ]
    }
}
];

var aProperties = [
    "to_ListTypeGroupAssignment/ListTypeGroup",
    "to_ListTypeGroupAssignment/ListTypeGroupDescription"
];
// (End of sample data)

// Call the function to get the result:
var aSelectedDataSet = extract(oDataSet, aProperties);

// For this snippet only: output the result in readable format
document.write('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(aSelectedDataSet, 0, 4)+'</pre>');
```

### Explanation of the algorithm:

The code is commented. This is how the algorithm works:

- The function is recursive and takes the current data, which will be just a sub section of the original data once the function is called recursively.
- The function also takes the path-style properties to select. Also this list will be shorter as the function is called recursively, so it only has those entries that are still relevant to the data section.
- The third argument is the path that has already been traversed. At the initial call this is just the empty string, but as the recursion kicks in, it will become 'to_ListTypeGroupAssignment/', and later even 'to_ListTypeGroupAssignment/ListTypeGroup/' (always with terminating slash).
- Each call of the function will return a part of the given data that matches the (path-style) selection.
- The function starts by identifying the type of the data: whether it is a primitive value (a string, number, boolean), or an array (which is the case at the initial call), or an (non-array) object.
- If it is an array, the function is just called recursively for each element without adding anything to the path. The result of each call is then stored in an array, which becomes the return value.
- If it is a primitive value, it means we recursed to a "leaf" in the "tree". And since we got here, we may assume the "path" was matching up until this point, and so the primitive value must be returned so it can be added to the result
- It it is an object, the select paths are traversed to see if the next level in those paths matches with an object property of the current data. If so, that property value is passed via a recursive call, while also adding that piece of the path to the "current" path

There are obviously the exceptions for `__metadata` and `results`, which are treated separately in the code.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer IMO. Unless there is some other exceptions?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to compare each property of oDataSet to each property of aSelectedDataSet

```
var res=[];
for (var key1 in oDataSet){
 for(var key2 in aSelectedDataSet ){
   if(key1==key2){
    res[key1]=oDataSet[key1];
   }
 }
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you define filter like so

```
var filter={
    __metadata:'',
    to_ListTypeGroupAssignment:{
        results:[{
            ListTypeGroup:'',
            ListTypeGroupDescription:''
        }]
    }

}
```

and apply it to data with recursion

```
function recursiveValue(filter,data){
    var res={};
    for(var key in filter){
        var val=data[key];
        var p=filter[key];
        if(val==='undefined') continue; 
        if(p===''){
            res[key] = val;
        }else if(Array.isArray(p)){
            var tmp = [];
            for(var i=0;i<val.length;i++){
                tmp.push(recursiveValue(filter[key][0],val[i]));
            }
            res[key] = tmp;
        }else if(typeof p=='object'){
            res[key] = recursiveValue(filter[key],val);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

like so

```
var results=[];
for(var i=0;i<oDataSet.length;i++){
    results.push(recursiveValue(filter,oDataSet[i]));
}
```

you get

```
console.log(results);
```

Comment: I try it but its not working,can you please use the jsFiddle which I provide? You dont refer to the results property, please use the code and I provide the exact output...

Comment: You code will not work(its not that simple...) since the aSelectedDataSet is just a var and its empty after the match it should be filled(like the output in the question...)

Answer (score 1):

One of the short solutions will be with lodash. It has `_.assignInWith(object, sources, [customizer])` function, using that you are going have the following:

```
var customizer = function(key) { return key in aPropertis }

var newSet = _.assignInWith({} , oDataSet, customizer)
```

However it is going to work only for first level properties.

Comment: Sorry but I cannot use lodash.

Comment: In our project we cannot use lodash or undercore :(

Comment: may i ask why? how you guys even working without it.

Comment: I know that there are very good but in our project currently we cannot (legal etc )use lodash now but in the future we will ...

Answer (score 1):

You could tackle this using functional programming techiniques made available by ES5. Try this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yh39of1b/3/

```
var aProperties = [
     "to_ListTypeGroupAssignment/ListTypeGroup",
     "to_ListTypeGroupAssignment/ListTypeGroupDescription"
];

//maps the properties you wish to capture
var propertyList = aProperties.map(function(properties) {
   return properties.split('/');
});

//reduces the oData array to the data you require
aSelectedDataSet = oData.reduce(function(existing,current){
     var obj = {};

     //each iteration of oData goes through each property group
     //first at the parent property level
     propertyList.forEach(function(property){
       if (typeof obj[property[0]] === 'undefined') {
        obj[property[0]] = {};
        obj[property[0]].results = [];
       }

       if(current[property[0]]) {
           //now at the child property level
           current[property[0]].results.forEach(function(result,index){
                 if(typeof obj[property[0]].results[index] === 'undefined')
                     obj[property[0]].results[index] = {};

                 obj[property[0]].results[index][property[1]] = result[property[1]];
           });
       }

   });
   //add the newly mapped object to the aSelectedDataSet array
   existing.push(obj);
   return existing;
},[]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant way, but works.

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/4rh6tt25/6/)

Compared nested structure and removed the keys which were not required.

Limitations:
1. `__metadata` is hardcoded
2. `results` is hardcoded

Your desired output is different then what is generated, difference is
Your output:

```
aSelectedDataSet[2].to_ListTypeGroupAssignment.results[1].ListTypeGroupDescription === 1
```

Whereas in the generated output it is:

```
aSelectedDataSet[2].to_ListTypeGroupAssignment.results[1].ListTypeGroupDescription === 6
```

I think, it was a typo in your question.

Code:

```
var convertPropertyRelation = function(propertiesArray) {
  if (!Array.isArray(propertiesArray))
    return [];
  var formattedProperties = {},
    i, len = propertiesArray.length,
    currentRelation;
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {

    currentRelation = propertiesArray[i].split('/');

    if (formattedProperties.hasOwnProperty(currentRelation[0])) {
      formattedProperties[currentRelation[0]].push(currentRelation[1]);
    } else {
      formattedProperties[currentRelation[0]] = [currentRelation[1]];
    }

  }
  return formattedProperties;
};

var generateDataSet = function() {
  var formattedProperties = convertPropertyRelation(aProperties),
    firstRelation = Object.keys(formattedProperties),
    i, len = firstRelation.length,
    j, resultArray, resultLength;

  var dataSet = oDataSet.map(function(dataSetObject) {
    for (var firstKey in dataSetObject) {

      if (firstKey === '__metadata') {

        continue;

      } else if (firstRelation.indexOf(firstKey) === -1) {

        delete dataSetObject[firstKey];

      } else {

        // if first relation is present
        if (dataSetObject.hasOwnProperty(firstKey)) {
          // results array in the firstRelation
          resultArray = dataSetObject[firstKey].results;
          // for all results
          for (j = 0, resultLength = resultArray.length; j < resultLength; j++) {
            // for all keys in current result
            for (var respectiveKey in resultArray[j]) {
              // if the key is present leave it as it is
              if (formattedProperties[firstKey].indexOf(respectiveKey) === -1) {
                delete resultArray[j][respectiveKey];
              }
            }

          }

        }

      }

    }
    return dataSetObject;
  });

  return dataSet;
};
```

Comment: Please post the code itself in your answer, not a link to it.

Comment: @Bergi I have added the code, but the answer added by Trincot, is more elegant and better